# ZFS mounting only one of my pools on boot

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I'm running ZFS on ubuntu 16.04.

I have two ZFS pools, each with 7 drives in RaidZ2.

Upon boot, only one of the two pools is mounted. I can mount the second one manually using

```
sudo zpool import vol2
```

At this point the second pool is mounted just fine.

How can I make sure that the first pool mounts upon boot?

Comment: I assume you are not running root on ZFS?  Which ZFS related systemd units are enabled; i.e zfs-mount.service, zfs.target, zed.service (or zfs-zed.service) etc.

Comment: root is not zfs. 
How can i find out which systemd units are enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You should enable several services as follows:

```
sudo systemctl enable zfs-import-cache.service
sudo systemctl enable zfs-import-scan.service
sudo systemctl enable zfs-mount.service
sudo systemctl enable zfs-share.service
sudo systemctl enable zfs-zed.service (depending on version may be zed.service)
```

and also:

```
sudo systemctl enable zfs.target
```

Reboot and see what happens.  Because of different versions and distributions, these may not all exist on you system.  Any that do should be enabled.

EDIT1:
To see if these services were properly enabled, execute the following command:

```
ls -oR /etc/systemd/ |grep zfs
```

The output should look something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 4096 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-mount.service.wants/  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 4096 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-share.service.wants/  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 4096 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs.target.wants/  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   39 22.01.2017 17:31 zed.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 34 22.01.2017 17:32 zfs.target -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs.target  
/etc/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.wants:  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 48 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-import-cache.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 47 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-import-scan.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-scan.service  
/etc/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.wants:  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 41 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-mount.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service  
/etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants:  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 48 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-import-cache.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 47 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-import-scan.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-scan.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 41 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-mount.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 41 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-share.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-share.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 39 22.01.2017 17:31 zfs-zed.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service
```

This will enable you to definitively determine whether the services were enabled even if you forgot the output when you enabled them or if you don't have access to the logs.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all this and still have the same problem. Only one of my zpools is mounted automatically upon reboot.

Comment: Wow, I really thought that was it.  I'll keep thinking about this though.  When you entered those commands did you get any error messages, any no-response-at-all, or did they all say "created a symlink in /etc/systemd/... etc."?

Comment: I don't have a the log anymore as I closed the session - sorry :-(

Comment: @muzzamo, I edited my question to include instructions for definitively determining whether those services are enabled or not.  But, I just saw that you solved your problem so I guess this is pointless!

Comment: turns out the updates didn't solve the problem and it was a red herring so i had to delete my answer.

Output from the command. Looks a lot more spartan: 

> ~$ ls -oR /etc/systemd/ |grep zfs lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 30 Sep 26 21:47 zfs.target -> /lib/systemd/system/zfs.target

Comment: If you could try the 5 commands at the top of my question one more time then see if the output of ` ls -oR /etc/systemd/ |grep zfs` changes.  If it doesn't change, I'll describe how to enable them manually.

Comment: here you are: http://pastebin.com/ZFJdVKHq

Comment: Ok, lets try it manually, though I'm concerned as to why the `enable` command didn't work.  First, try `ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service /etc/systemd/system/zed.service` and `ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-scan.service /etc/systemd/system/zfs-import-scan.service`  and then the same thing for `zfs-import-cache.service`.  After those 3 commands, assuming there are no errors, try rebooting.

Comment: man that didnt work for me either, although the latter two were missing. still having this issue, on a first time install of rhel 7.3, after accidentally install for 7 first, where it wasnt working.