# zfs will not import or mount on boot (fedora)

Tags: zfs

I just upgraded my system from Fedora 35 to Fedora 37.  I rebuilt ZFS and I am able to import and mount my filesystems manually.  However, no matter what I do, they do no mount at startup.  I am not sure what else to try.

I've done the following:
[Ensured that all ZFS related services are enabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338260/zfs-mounting-only-one-of-my-pools-on-boot/338522#338522)

I've also recreated the ZFS Cache.

The status of `systemctl status zfs-import-cache.service`

```
         Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
         Active: inactive (dead)
           Docs: man:zpool(8)
```

This is interesting:
`systemctl status zfs-mount.service`

```
○ zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
  Condition: start condition failed at Wed 2023-03-01 13:59:56 EST; 7min ago
       Docs: man:zfs(8)

Mar 01 13:59:56 alpha systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems was skipped because of a failed condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/module/zfs).
```

I found an older copy of boot.log that shows the services starting:

```
[  OK  ] Reached target ZFS pool import target.
[  OK  ] Stopped target ZFS pool import target.
         Starting Import ZFS pools by cache file...
[  OK  ] Finished Import ZFS pools by cache file.
[  OK  ] Reached target ZFS pool import target.
         Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
[  OK  ] Finished Mount ZFS filesystems.
[  OK  ] Started ZFS Event Daemon (zed).
```

But the current ones are empty. Which is implies that the services aren't enabled. But they are enabled.

Any ideas what else to look at or try?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs to see why the service isn't starting?

Comment: Which service? I posted above the output of two services.  I can't find any other log information other than what systemd gives me.

Comment: The second one states that the start condition failed. One of the places to find more information is in the `/var/log ` directory. You can look at the conf file or use Google to find out what the log file is. There is also `/var/log/messages`. Are you not familiar with any of that?

Comment: /var/log/messages is a great place to check for errors or logs when something tries to load and fails.  However, in this case it's not starting.  I made some edits above to show that boot.log represents nothing is even attempted to start.

Comment: Again, it says in the message that it didn't start because a condition failed. `/var/log/messages` may have information on why that happened. So do other log files. In any event, you can look at what's wrong with the path that's denoted in the message and if it even exists.

Comment: Again, an exhaustive look through the logs does not reveal anything that I did not cover. Moreover, the error "(ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/module/zfs)." is directly from the systemd file.  However, /sys/module/zfs is, in fact, a directory.  So failure condition is not correct.  I did solve this though, and no. The answer wasn't in the logs.

Comment: Had you put that in the question, then I'd have recognized it and moved on. Your original question gave no indication that you had attempted to do anything after finding that the service wasn't started. That's why I mentioned the message and the logs. In any Unix-based OS whether it's Fedora, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc, one of the first things is to examine the logs which is why that's usually mentioned when there is a question regarding an issue like this. If what you did worked, then that's great.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this comes as a change in the way ZFS is handling mounting filesystems.

Take a look here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ZFS

The correct method now relies on the zed service (which is enabled)

Following these steps makes the filesystem mount on boot again.

- Make sure the zed service is running:
  `systemctl enable zfs-zed.service`
- Create an empty file for each pool
  `touch /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/<pool-name>`
- Spark zed into action:
  `zfs set canmount=off <pool>`
  Now, the files in `/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/` should no longer be empty.
- Set canmount back on:
  `zfs set canmount=off <pool>`
- Reboot

This solved it for me.
One dead give away is that the ZFS import service is masked and cannot be enabled.